# Get the value passed inside of a C# Expression value

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I have the below class

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I have the below code

```
int x = 1;
Expression<Func<TestClass, bool>> predicate = c => c.TestProperty == x;
Console.WriteLine(predicate.ToString());
```

The `predicate.ToString()` is returning `c => (c.TestProperty == value(Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).x)`

Is there any way to evaluate the Expression in order to return `c => (c.TestProperty == 1)`

Note that it is not possible to create the expression with the value of x set as shown below

```
Expression<Func<TestClass, bool>> predicate = c => c.TestProperty == 1;
```

Comment: No, this isn't possible, unless you want to get absurdly complicated with reflection over the innards. The reason is that the capture of `x` generates a closure whose value is only reflected at runtime. The assignment to `x` is *not* captured in the expression, and while you can compile and execute the expression, you can't then turn the resulting code back into an expression, so that's no help.  What you can do in this case is have a `Func<int, TestClass, bool>` that captures the value as a parameter, and then apply that to get another expression.

Comment: Can you change the function to receive `x` as well? `Expression<Func<TestClass, int, bool>>`

Comment: @JeroenMostert for this concrete case it is not that complicated. Though relies on the generation patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very easy and robust (relies on current expression generation patterns) but can be achieved with visitor:

```cs
class MySimpleConstantReplacingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression is ConstantExpression ce && node.Member is FieldInfo fe) // possibly check as PropertyInfo JIC
        {
            return Expression.Constant(fe.GetValue(ce.Value));
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
int xx = 1;
Expression<Func<TestClass, bool>> predicate = c => c.TestProperty == xx;
var modifiedExpression = new MySimpleConstantReplacingVisitor().Visit(predicate);
Console.WriteLine(modifiedExpression.ToString()); // prints "c => (c.TestProperty == 1)"
```

Note that this covers only simple cases (like the one in the example) and potentially there could be a lot of caveats. I don't know if there are libraries which do exactly what you need but there is quite a lot of libraries which handle analyzing the expression trees. Like almost every LINQ-based ORM - for example EF Core (see [`ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/7a7754f6553eb89d16a994c0ba98f3f62eab3f3b/src/EFCore/Query/Internal/ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.cs) for example, [check for closure](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/7a7754f6553eb89d16a994c0ba98f3f62eab3f3b/src/EFCore/Query/Internal/ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.cs#L624) part can be interesting). Or [Serialize.Linq](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq) library.